# Get all issues in Github Milestone

Tags: java, github-api, github-api-v3

I want to get all issues in Github with Java client for exact Milestone. I tried this:

```
public void listClosedIssuesInMilestone(String host, String token, String repository_name, String milestone_name) throws IOException
    {

        GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient(host);
        client.setOAuth2Token(token);

        RepositoryService service = new RepositoryService(client);

        List<Repository> repositories = service.getRepositories();

        MilestoneService milestones = new MilestoneService(client);

        for (int z = 0; z < repositories.size(); z++)
        {
            Repository repository = repositories.get(z);

            if (repository.getName().equals(repository_name)) {

                List<Milestone> closedMilestones = milestones.getMilestones(repository, "closed");  

                for (int i = 0; i < closedMilestones.size(); i++)
                {
                    Milestone milestone = closedMilestones.get(i);

                    if (milestone.getTitle().equals(milestone_name)) {

                        // TODO get closed issues here
                    }
                }

            }              
        }
    }
```

But I can't find a way to implement this. I can't get the list of issues into milestone. Can you advice how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `IssueService`.  Sorry I don't have any project set up to test.  If passing the name directly to milestone doesn't work you may need to get `MileStoneService` by name and pass the number to the milestone filter.

Something like

```
RepositoryService service = new RepositoryService(client);
List<Repository> repositories = service.getRepositories();
Repository repository = null;

// Get the repository matching name
for(Repository repo:repositories) {
  if(repo.getName().equals(repository_name)) {
    repository = repo;
    break;
  }
}

List<Issue> issues = new ArrayList<>();
// Get issues in repository
if(repository != null) {
  IssueService issueService = new IssueService(client);
  Map<String,String> filters = new HashMap<>();
  filters.put(IssueService.FILTER_STATE,IssueService.STATE_CLOSED);
  filters.put(IssueService.FILTER_MILESTONE,milestone_name);
  issues = issueService.getIssues(repository,filters);
}
```